# How can I get the sketch going that came with my TTDO LoRa oled esp32?

Tags: esp32

I got this device:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1-Pcs-TTGO-LORA32-V2-0-433-868Mhz-ESP32-LoRa-OLED-0-96-Inch-Blue-Display/32847499968.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.MnBocO

It came installed with a program that sent LoRa packets and displayed on the oled display what it was doing.

Despite downloading and installing and reinstalling a vast array of libraries and examples and sketches, I don't seem to be able to find where the source code is for the original program, or how to install it via Arduino. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: So, you've overwritten the supplied firmware, and now want to get it back? It's highly doubtful that the original firmware was written using Arduino, more likely using ESP32 IDF